# Android Studio Firebase Recyclerview upgrading error

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have to develop a `Recyclerview` with `PopulateViewHolder` in an older version of Firebase. Now I'm trying to upgrade the version (not at the last one) and I don't know how to use `onBindHolder` or anything about this new kind of `RecyclerView`.

Here is how I had the setup:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, EventViewHolder>(

            Event.class,
            R.layout.event_row,
            EventViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase.orderByChild("timeStamp")

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final EventViewHolder viewHolder, final Event model, final int position) {
            final String id = getRef(position).getKey().toString().trim();

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDateWords(model.getDateWords());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());

        }
    };

    mEventList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

public static class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public EventViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
}
```

And here it's how I'm trying to do now:

```
Query searchQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("timeStamp");

    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Event>()
            .setQuery(searchQuery, Event.class)
            .build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, EventViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final EventViewHolder viewHolder, int position, Event model) {
            final String id = getRef(position).getKey().toString().trim();

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDateWords(model.getDateWords());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            return null;
        }
    };

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    mEventList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

The `ViewHolder` Class is the same.

[Here is the error](https://pastebin.com/WWkES2bV)

Actually, I'm asking for tutorial, because I only find those that make the adapter separately, but I wanna have it in the same activity.

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the link to a screenshot of the error message, with the actual stack trace in text. That allows it to be searched and makes it faster for folks to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder` method, instead of returning a view you are returning `null`. To solve this, please add the following lines of code inside this method:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    return new EventViewHolder(view);
}
```

In which `item_layout` is a custom layout for your item. If you want to use instead of this layout a built-in XML layout document that is part of the Android OS, you can use:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```